# How to set generic parameter of class dynamically?

Tags: java, generics

I have generic class `TableView<>` where i need to set type, which is not known in advance and is resolved based on some condition.

See code:

```
Class clazz = null;
switch($something)
{
    case $case1: clazz = $someClass1;
    case $case2: clazz = $someClass2;
    ...
}
TableView<clazz> = new TableView<clazz>(); //<- compilation problem here: "clazz cannot be resolved to a type"
```

Comment: Not possible. Generics are a compile-time mechanism and don't exist at run-time (for the most part). Use something like `TableView<Object>` or `TableView<MyCommonInterface>` and then decide how you'll configure the table (e.g. via an interface, via annotations, via inspecting the class structure using reflection, via a configuration file, etc.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not possible "dynamically", as generic type information is erased at runtime. Everything is done at compile-time, based on type inference by the compiler. If you want to create a certain instance bound to a type based on a condition, one way is create a factory method that returns the instance with the desired type argument:

```
TableView<? extends Number> createTableView(condition) {
    switch (condition) {
    case x:
        return new TableView<Double>();
    ...
    default:
        return new TableView<Integer>();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any other solution, even if the drawback is the compiler will treat the TableView as containing Number (meaning only public methods of Number will be accessible later in the code)

Answer (score 0):

Generics must be know at the compilation time as it only guarantees compile time safety. In the runtime, all generic types are `Object`. Therfore, you cannot use variable to declare generic type of class/method